# Debt Schedule - Subtracting in equal proportions until 0, then moving on to next debt

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with a debt schedule, but I would like to do a waterfall calculation.

For example: every quarter a company pays down ~$20M of debt, evenly distributed over 3 different debt balances with 3 different oustanding balances. However, the payment of $20M is constant, but I would like to keep flowing down that $20M until each debt balances = 0.

So far, I have figured out the formula shown below (Looking at Term Debt, revolver Pt. 1, and Revolver Pt.2. The problem is it doesn't stop after I reach 0... (i.e. revolver part 2 pays down to -7.0 and -18.2.)

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!!!!

[My Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wsC1.png)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1764922/edit) to include your formula as text

Comment: not sure why you need `SUM()` , but if you choose to use it I think you need to move the end parenthesis of the sum to right after your second `S70`